# Javax Websocket commit login data with path params, good practice?

Tags: java, authentication, websocket

I'm working on a simple chat app, with a java backend. To authenticate my users I'm storing the username and a hashed password in my database to later compare it with the incoming password. My question is now how to commit the user login data, what is the best practice here? At the moment I transfer username and password by adding them as path params, when connecting to the websocket server. Is this a good way to achive my goal or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

That actually depends on many things. If your application also supports HTTP requests, then I suggest you to use http authentication methods and store a session id in cookie. Websockets are capable of sending cookies to server. This is one of the cleanest ways.

Or, you could develop your application, forcing users to enter their username and password as the first message they send, then authenticate those credentials and authorize user, and in case of an exception, close the websocket (not best practice).

There is one other way that we used in our application which is not common but we did it anyways and its working fine for us, was to authenticate our user in different server and give them a `token`. Since our websocket server was separate from authentication server and we were not using valid SSO (Single Sign On) methods, cookies could not be a good solution (Web browsers do not provide a cookie of an address A to server with address B). So we made up our own protocol and added the `token` provided from authentication server, inside [`sec-websocket-protocol`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.3.4) and sent it to the server. The websocket server then checks and validates the token using authentication server.